# How to make rotated elements in a flexbox fixed to the right side of a page?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a small vertical text "watermark" background that runs up the right side of some reveal.js slides. I have gotten as far as the fact that I need to use `transform` to rotate any elements that I want to run vertically up the length of the right side of the page.

The problem is that it seems that a lot of the geometry calculations occur *before* transformations occur, and the result is that the geometry gets miscalculated when I try to align the elements with a flexbox. Here is a basic example that *almost* works:

```css
div.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: grey;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="item" style="width: 200px">
    Some text
</div>
<img class="item" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAUCAYAAAB7wJiVAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAAB3RJTUUH4gYGDxYxe2lIhQAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAGiSURBVFjD7ZmxzYMwEIVfonQMkA1SUNAiUYBEmYKMkDEyg8fICEeRnhRIMEAkmMDpSUWkS4WU5geMjfiD/EnuzNPZjzvZ5w0zMyz/hp3dAn1erxcejweyLEOapgCAJEkQRRFc14XjOKO1NroZUtc1iqJAnue43+8AgDAMEQQBfN/H4XBYrRHv9xu32w2n06l3HhHheDxitxvx//NEpJQshGAAvUMIwVJKXhtN03Acx4Pr70Ycx9w0zaDuJEOqqmLP80YH43keV1W1GjPatlUy49uUtm3NGiKlVDLj25S1ZAoRKa+/G0Rk1pAxZaqvfK2hVE1dfzf6ShdUS5VuML9eusqy1N6Dsiz/1N+qnCqKotA+mZjQWJIsy2bVUDIkz3PtYExoLEl3z5hLQ8mQ7p6hgwmNNbO1W6BGkiSzaigZEoahdjAmNJYkiqJZNZQMCYJAOxgTGkviuu6sGkqG+L6vHYwJjSVxHAdENPl7IupvNtqLoW2d2OaibS7Olylj+lpENJgZHZPfQ57PJ67XKy6XS+88IQTO5zP2+719oLIPVL/HBwWcbe23UyTxAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="" />
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the outer `div` has a width that is calculated based on the width of the non-rotated flexbox elements, and as a result the elements show up offset from the side of the page.

If I try to fix this by changing `align-items` to `flex-end`, the result is that each element is aligned to a different

```css
div.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: grey;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.item {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="item" style="width: 200px">
    Some text
</div>
<img class="item" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAUCAYAAAB7wJiVAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAAB3RJTUUH4gYGDxYxe2lIhQAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAGiSURBVFjD7ZmxzYMwEIVfonQMkA1SUNAiUYBEmYKMkDEyg8fICEeRnhRIMEAkmMDpSUWkS4WU5geMjfiD/EnuzNPZjzvZ5w0zMyz/hp3dAn1erxcejweyLEOapgCAJEkQRRFc14XjOKO1NroZUtc1iqJAnue43+8AgDAMEQQBfN/H4XBYrRHv9xu32w2n06l3HhHheDxitxvx//NEpJQshGAAvUMIwVJKXhtN03Acx4Pr70Ycx9w0zaDuJEOqqmLP80YH43keV1W1GjPatlUy49uUtm3NGiKlVDLj25S1ZAoRKa+/G0Rk1pAxZaqvfK2hVE1dfzf6ShdUS5VuML9eusqy1N6Dsiz/1N+qnCqKotA+mZjQWJIsy2bVUDIkz3PtYExoLEl3z5hLQ8mQ7p6hgwmNNbO1W6BGkiSzaigZEoahdjAmNJYkiqJZNZQMCYJAOxgTGkviuu6sGkqG+L6vHYwJjSVxHAdENPl7IupvNtqLoW2d2OaibS7Olylj+lpENJgZHZPfQ57PJ67XKy6XS+88IQTO5zP2+719oLIPVL/HBwWcbe23UyTxAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="" />
</div>
```

I'm guessing that the reason for this is that the calculations of where to put the baselines are done based on the pre-rotation versions of the items, and then they get rotated into the positions you see there.

What is the correct way to do something like this? Is there any way to create an element where the geometry calculations about its position will be calculated *after* the rotations take place?

Answer (score 3):

Adjust `transform-origin` and rely on translation without changing the alignement

Here is on the left side :

```css
div.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: grey;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.item {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
    transform-origin:top left;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="item" style="width: 200px">
    Some text
</div>
<img class="item" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" />
</div>
```

And here is on the right side:

```css
div.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: grey;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.item {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100%);
    transform-origin:top right;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="item" style="width: 200px">
    Some text
</div>
<img class="item" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. This seems to work for the MWE that I made for this example, but not for my actual use case for some reason. Can you maybe explain how this works in more detail so that I can try to debug?

Comment: @Paul by default the transform origin is the center of your element ... when you change it you define from where you will rotate the element and then the transalation with 100% will adjust the position ... maybe you can share your full code to see the issue ?

Comment: I think it's too complicated at the moment. In a few days I'll try and work up an actual MWE that has the pathological behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want the width of the text to affect the width of the **outer**, then use a *writing-mode* vertical for it.

For the image, it would be better to have an image that doesn't need to be rotated. But, if this is the case, use transform translate and transform origin, just like in Temani Afif answer

```css
div.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background: red;
}

img.item {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="item">
    Some text
  </div>
  <img class="item" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    alt="" />
</div>
```